# Jquery preencher <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com problema pra preencher um combo.

No retorno do JS o data vem toda a lista, mas no preencher não mostra.

Meu Js :

```
  function CarregaCliente() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Clientes/SelecionarCliente",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

                $("#cliente").empty();

                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, element) {                    
                    $("#cliente").append('<option value=' + element.Id + '>' + element.Nome + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cliente</label>
                <select id="cliente" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
```

Retorno data:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como aparece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

minhas bibliotecas:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/relatorio.js"></script>
```

Comment: Como e onde vc está chamando a função?

Comment: No mesmo arquivo Js logo ao iniciar o documento ---- $(document).ready(function () {  

    CarregaCliente();

Comment: Já tentou retirando esse `async: false,`? Ele é totalmente não recomendado. Até porque nem precisa, já que o Ajax só é executado se a função for executada após o DOM...

Comment: @Sam deu certo obrigada.. Apanhando aqui a mais de 2h

Comment: Coloque como resposta que que eu marco com certo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não se usa `async: false,` em Ajax. O Ajax deve ser processado de forma assíncrona. Já que o Ajax só é processado quando uma função for chamada após o DOM, faz menos sentido ainda usá-lo de forma síncrona.

Então basta retirar o `async: false,` que o select será populado normalmente:

```
function CarregaCliente() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/Clientes/SelecionarCliente",
         // async: false, 
         success: function (data) {

             $("#cliente").empty();

             console.log(data);
             $.each(data, function (i, element) {                    
                 $("#cliente").append('<option value=' + element.Id + '>' + element.Nome + '</option>');
             });
         }
     });
 }

 $(document).ready(function () { CarregaCliente(); });
```